# prototype.js Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater call own function to update

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

Anyone know if it is possible to make the PeriodicalUpdater pass the data it received to a function I assign to update the desired field?

I want to process the data I receive and then have the PeriodicalUpdater function update the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can pass it an onsuccess callback, just like you do for a any other AjaxRequest.

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('container', '/someurl', {
  method: 'get', 
  frequency: 3, 
  decay: 2;
  onsuccess: function(response){
     myCustomFunction(response.responseText);
  }
});

function myCustomFunction(data){
  /* do something */
}
```

See [Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalUpdater) and [Ajax Options](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options).

Comment: So is it possible to prevent it from updating? I think I just need it to run the call and not insert anything because the field I need to be updated has to be updated in a very particular way

Comment: You could have a hidden div and pass that as the 'container', in that way, nothing visible would be updated and you still have control of what to updated using your custom function

Comment: Nice idea. I have already changed it to ajax.request but maybe I could just update an empty div.

Thanks for the idea